# Why typescript adds two numbers like strings?

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

I know typescript is strongly typed, but why the following code prints `12` instead of `3`?

```
function add_numbers(a: number, b: number){
    return a + b;
}

var a = '1';
var b = 2;

var result = add_numbers(<number><any>a, b);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I mean, clearly one is string delimited, right?

Comment: Because `<number><any>a` bypasses any strong typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript is strongly typed at compile time, it can't prevent runtime errors if you write poor code. You've overridden the types using `<any>` to trick the compiler and so normal javascript behavior of adding a string to number is executed when your function runs.

If you remove the casting you're doing with `<number><any>` you'll see that TypeScript catches and flags your error.

Answer (score 1):

The ***any*** type holds a special place in the TypeScript type system. It gives you an escape hatch from the type system to tell the compiler to bugger off. any is compatible with any and all types in the type system. This means that anything can be assigned to it and it can be assigned to anything. This is demonstrated in the example below:

```
var power: any;

// Takes any and all types
power = '123';
power = 123;

// Is compatible with all types
var num: number;
power = num;
num = power;
```

For Ref : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html

Answer (score 1):

At the end, typescript is always converted to javascript, so what you are doing is adding the string '1' and the number 2. Javascript converts the number to a string, because it is not possible to add a string and a number.

if you delare a type for the variables passed to the function, the typescript transpiler will output an error:

```
var a: number = '1';
var b: number = 1;

add_numbers(a, b);
```

error:

> type mismatch in first line

```
var a: string = '1';
var b: number = 1;

add_numbers(a, b);
```

error:

> wrong parameter type in function call